# Distribute String Line Break into Adjacent Cell Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to extract the data from Line break to adjacent cell i have tried different formulas from online sources but all use some of delimiter but this one does not have any delimiter.

I hope someone can help me with this i would appreciate your help.

[image]

```
(661) 298-3070 
(661) 526-4640
(661) 250-9492
(661) 857-0317
(661) 857-0147
(661) 298-3070
(661) 891-1139
```

I want to keep these bracket () in when separated into adjacent cell. Looking for a formula to fix this,

Result would be like this:

[image]

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: I have pasted an image above which contains result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using `FILTERXML()` Function

[image: Formula_Solution]

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(10),"</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y"))
```

---

Or, If you are in **MS365** and when writing the formula if **Beta Channel** is enabled then try using `TEXTSPLIT()`

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=TEXTSPLIT(A3,CHAR(10))
```

---

Edit,

Two more alternative approach using Formula,

[image: Formula_Solution]

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(10),"</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y["&COLUMN(A1)&"]"),"")
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A3,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN(A1)*100-99,100))
```

Comment: Thank you i am using the FilterXML but its repeating the same phone number instead of 2nd third and so one

Comment: What is your Excel version?

Comment: its MS Excel 365

Comment: Then dont think it should be since I am also using `MS365` please use the formula I have provided along with `TRANSPOSE()` Function

Comment: @HSHO try using this one `=FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(10),"</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y["&COLUMN(A1)&"]")` need to drag right

Comment: @HSHO please check I have edited the answers with two more alternative approaches.

Comment: Thank you very much now its working with updated functions. Can you please add just one thing if there are 7 numbers if i split to 8th cell it should not give an `#Value` error or any error `=FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(10),"</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y["&COLUMN(A1)&"]")
`

Comment: Yes just wrap the whole formula within `IFERROR()` Functions, but If you are using MS365 then the one with `TRANSPOSE()` Function should work,

Answer (score 2):

Using the text-to-columns feature, you should be able to complete using the following steps:

1. Select your data.
2. Open the text-to-columns feature from Data tab.
3. Choose "delimited" in step-1 of the wizard.
4. De-select "tab" delimiter and select **only** "other" as your type of delimiter.
5. Then next to the other input your cursor and press CTRL-J.  The preview should be accurate and you're done.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I was looking for a formula to achieve this.

Comment: Yes it works i requested in my questions that i am looking for formula. I was aware that text to column works for this.

Comment: In that case I would consider adjusting your question to reflect this requirement. As written, you did not require a formula but simply mentioned you have tried formulas.

Comment: I am sorry that if i could not elaborate it well